# How to bring together multiple delta tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with IDs and primary information.  I also have two delta tables keyed on ID and date of change.  I need to build a view that merges these three tables together indicating all changes over time.

Main Table:

```
ID  Name
--  ------------------
1   Bob Jones
2   Dave Smith
```

First Attribute Table:

```
ID  Date        Attr1
--  ----------  -----
1   01/01/2013  25
1   02/15/2013  33
1   02/17/2013  47
1   03/02/2013  58
2   02/01/2013  1
...
```

Second Attribute Table

```
ID  Date        Attr2
--  ----------  -----
1   01/01/2013  ABC
1   01/05/2013  DEF
1   01/15/2013  RST
1   02/10/2013  XYZ
1   02/15/2013  Foo
1   03/05/2013  Blah
2   02/01/2013  Two
...
```

Based on that data, for Bob Jones, I need the view to return the following:

```
ID  Name         Date        Attr1  Attr2
--  -----------  ----------  -----  -----
1   Bob Jones    01/01/2013  25     ABC
1   Bob Jones    01/05/2013  25     DEF
1   Bob Jones    01/15/2013  25     RST
1   Bob Jones    02/10/2013  25     XYZ
1   Bob Jones    02/15/2013  33     Foo
1   Bob Jones    02/17/2013  47     Foo
1   Bob Jones    03/02/2013  58     Foo
1   Bob Jones    03/05/2013  58     Blah
```

I tried outer joining the attribute tables to get all change values ordered by date and then used an outer join on the entire query with itself to get "prior" records:

```
with qry as (
  select
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.ID, a.DATE),
    m.ID,
    m.Name,
    a.DATE,
    a.Attr1,
    a.Attr2
  from Main m
  inner join (
    select
      COALESCE(a1.ID, a2.ID) as ID,
      COALESCE(a1.LOAD_DATE, a2.LOAD_DATE) as LOAD_DATE,
      a1.Attr1,
      a2.Attr2
    from Attributes1 a1
    full outer join Attributes2 a2
      on (a1.ID = a2.ID and a1.DATE = a2.DATE)
  ) a on (a.ID = m.ID)
)
select
  COALESCE(qry.ID, prev.ID) as ID,
  COALESCE(qry.Name, prev.Name) as Name,
  COALESCE(qry.DATE, prev.DATE) as DATE,
  COALESCE(qry.Attr1, prev.Attr1) as Attr1,
  COALESCE(qry.Attr2, prev.Attr2) as Attr2,
from qry
left join qry prev
  on (prev.rownum = qry.rownum - 1)
order by ID, DATE
```

However, that doesn't work when one attribute table changes quicker than the other because the attributes that didn't change are null in the results of the attribute table join and if two nulls show up back-to-back, the coalesce will return a null when I need the last non-null value that was in that column.

Can this even be done in a view in SQL Server 2012?